# Generic Visitor pattern library for polymorphic virtual class hierarchies

Tags: c++, design-patterns, library, c++20, visitor-pattern

Inspired by this [cppcon talk from Fedor Pikus about design patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdtYi0vvct0) and some real-world need I implemented a library that allows the user to add a generic visitor pattern capabilities to class hierarchies based on vanilla C++ runtime polymorphism with virtual functions. There were 2 requirements I wanted to follow:

1. Generic return type, the same as when using `std::visit` on a `std::variant`.
2. Allow as much forward declarations as reasonably possible, to decouple the client from any code (i.e. concrete implementations) that one doesn't need to know.

The code is on my github: https://github.com/ldrozdz93/cpp-visitor-pattern.

I'll also paste it here, as it's quite short.

The test file:

```
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#include "catch.hpp"
#include "vstor/vstor.hpp"

namespace {

using vstor::Overloaded;
using vstor::VisitableFor;
using vstor::VisitableImpl;
using vstor::VisitableListVariant;

// NOTE: below code order is important from the testing POV

// GIVEN a forward-declared list of visitables,
struct VisitablesVariant;

// WHEN creating a visitable base,
// THEN it can be declared with an incomplete type
struct Base : VisitableFor<VisitablesVariant> {
};

// AND list of visitables can be any template list
template <typename...>
struct AnyList;
struct D1;
struct D2;

using ListOfVisitables = AnyList<D1, D2>;

// AND require complete type only when visitation is used
struct VisitablesVariant : VisitableListVariant<ListOfVisitables> {
    using VisitableListVariant<ListOfVisitables>::VisitableListVariant;
};

template <typename Impl>
struct BaseImpl : VisitableImpl<Impl, Base> {
};

struct D1 : BaseImpl<D1> {
};
struct D2 : BaseImpl<D2> {
};

TEST_CASE("Visitor")
{
    using std::string;
    GIVEN("Polymorphic class hierarchy")
    {
        D2 d2{};
        WHEN("object is mutable")
        {
            Base& b = d2;
            THEN("can be visited")
            {
                string res =
                    b.visit_by(Overloaded{[](D1&) { return "D1"; }, [](D2&) { return "D2"; }});
                REQUIRE(res == "D2");
            }
        }
        WHEN("object is const")
        {
            const Base& b = d2;
            THEN("can be visited")
            {
                string res = b.visit_by(
                    Overloaded{[](const D1&) { return "D1"; }, [](const D2&) { return "D2"; }});
                REQUIRE(res == "D2");
            }
        }
        WHEN("object is rvalue")
        {
            THEN("can be visited")
            {
                // TODO: should non-const references be allowed to bind to rvalues?
                string res =
                    D1{}.visit_by(Overloaded{[](D1&) { return "D1"; }, [](D2&) { return "D2"; }});
                REQUIRE(res == "D1");
            }
        }

        // TODO: will constexpr ever work here?
        //        WHEN("object is constexpr")
        //        {
        //            constexpr const D1 d1{};
        //            THEN("can be visited")
        //            {
        //                constexpr int res = d1.visit_by(
        //                    overloaded{[](const D1&) { return 1; }, [](const D2&) { return 2; }});
        //                STATIC_REQUIRE(res == "D2");
        //            }
        //        }
    }
}

TEST_CASE("Utilities")
{
    SECTION("Overloaded")
    {
        // TODO: add better tests.

        using namespace std::string_literals;
        auto sut = vstor::detail::Overloaded{
            [](char) { return "char"s; },
            [](int) { return "int"s; },
            [](float) { return "float"s; },
        };
        REQUIRE("char" == sut(char{}));
        REQUIRE("int" == sut(int{}));
        REQUIRE("float" == sut(float{}));
    }
}

}  // namespace
```

And the implementation file:

```
#ifndef VSTOR_HPP
#define VSTOR_HPP

#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

namespace vstor {

namespace detail {

/**
 * A commonly used template for creating lambda-based callable overload sets.
 *
 * @todo add possibility to set a fixed required return type
 * */
template <class... Ts>
class Overloaded : public Ts... {
public:
    using Ts::operator()...;
};
#if __cpp_deduction_guides < 201907L  // if CTAD for aggregates and aliases not supported
template <class... Ts>
Overloaded(Ts...) -> Overloaded<Ts...>;
#endif

// TODO: implement concept: invocable_with_each_variant_option<F, VisitablesVariant>

/**
 * A tag class for marking every VisitableFor<...> instance. Used instead of clunky sfinae for
 * checking if a given type is a subclass of an instantiation of VisitableFor<...> template.
 * */
struct VisitableFor_BaseTag {
};
template <typename T>
concept AnyVisitableFor = std::is_base_of_v<VisitableFor_BaseTag, T>;

/**
 * A base class for all Visitable classes, that perform the double dispatch of the visitor pattern.
 * The concrete implementations of this base participate in the first dispatch by virtual functions.
 * The second dispatch is performed as a std::visit visitation of possible visitables.
 *
 * @tparam Variant - a maybe-incomplete class, that at the point of instantiation must be a class
 * derived from VisitableListVariant<...>. Note it's not checked by any concept, because that would
 * require an eager instantiation of the list of possible visitable variants, which is not intended.
 * */
template <typename Variant>
class VisitableFor : public VisitableFor_BaseTag {
public:
    using VisitableVariant = Variant;

    virtual VisitableVariant as_variant() const noexcept = 0;

    /**
     * Performs visitation on 'this' by the same rules as std::visit does.
     */
    template <typename Visitor>
    // requires invocable_with_each_variant_option<Visitor, VisitableVariant>
    decltype(auto) visit_by(Visitor&& visitor);

    template <typename Visitor>
    // requires invocable_with_each_variant_option<Visitor, VisitableVariant>
    decltype(auto) visit_by(Visitor&& visitor) const;
};

template <typename Variant>
template <typename Visitor>
decltype(auto) VisitableFor<Variant>::visit_by(Visitor&& visitor)
{
    auto invoke_visitor_after_dereference_and_deconst = [&](auto&& v) -> decltype(auto) {
        // NOTE: it's safe to const_cast, because the pointee of the pointer inside the visitable
        // variant is in fact 'this', so it has the same cv-qualification
        using NonConstVisitable = std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*std::forward<decltype(v)>(v))>;
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor),
                           const_cast<NonConstVisitable&>(*std::forward<decltype(v)>(v)));
    };
    // NOTE: the whole pattern cannot be noexcept friendly due to std::visit possibly throwing
    return std::visit(invoke_visitor_after_dereference_and_deconst, as_variant().as_std_variant());
}

template <typename Variant>
template <typename Visitor>
decltype(auto) VisitableFor<Variant>::visit_by(Visitor&& visitor) const
{
    auto invoke_visitor_after_dereference = [&](auto&& v) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), *std::forward<decltype(v)>(v));
    };

    return std::visit(invoke_visitor_after_dereference, as_variant().as_std_variant());
}

/**
 * Base class for the concrete visitable implementation.
 *
 * @tparam CrtpImpl - CRTP class that must be a part of the previously-defined VisitableVariant.
 * It's incomplete due to CRTP usage.
 *
 * @tparam Base - The concrete VisitableFor<...> base class this implementation is based on.
 * */
template <typename CrtpImpl, AnyVisitableFor Base>
class VisitableImpl : public Base {
public:
    using VisitableVariant = typename Base::VisitableVariant;

    /**
     * This method is const, without any non-const overload for the following reason: the
     * return value can be incomplete until used. The return value for a non-const overload would
     * need to differ from the const overload. Doing that with type traits would require a complete
     * VisitableVariant class, which we want to avoid, so the end user would need to provide 2
     * incomplete VisitableVariants that would differ from each other only with the possible variant
     * being const. Instead, we const_cast the const away in case we know the instance being worked
     * with is in fact non-const.
     *
     * @returns 'this' as one of the possible variant options.
     * */
    VisitableVariant as_variant() const noexcept final
    {
        return VisitableVariant{static_cast<const CrtpImpl*>(this)};
    }
};
template <typename... Args>
using StdVariantBase = std::variant<const Args* const...>;

/**
 * Base class for aggregating maybe-incomplete classes possible for visitation.
 *
 * @tparam Visitables - a variadic list of maybe-incomplete visitables.
 * */
template <typename... Visitables>
class VisitableListVariant : private StdVariantBase<Visitables...> {
public:
    using VariantBase = StdVariantBase<Visitables...>;
    using VariantBase::VariantBase;
    VariantBase& as_std_variant() & noexcept { return *this; }
    const VariantBase& as_std_variant() const& noexcept { return *this; }
};

/**
 * Specialization of VisitableListVariant that unfolds any list-like template into a proper
 * VisitableListVariant. It's intended to be used in case the user is keeping the visitable classes
 * as some templated list for any reason.
 *
 * @tparam AnyList - any template in a form of TemplateName<T1, T2, ...>,
 * ex: 'std::variant<T1, T2>' or 'boost::mpl::list<T1, T2>'
 * */
template <template <typename...> typename AnyList, typename... Visitables>
class VisitableListVariant<AnyList<Visitables...>> : public VisitableListVariant<Visitables...> {
public:
    using VisitableListVariant<Visitables...>::VisitableListVariant;
};

}  // namespace detail

using detail::Overloaded;
using detail::VisitableFor;
using detail::VisitableImpl;
using detail::VisitableListVariant;
}  // namespace vstor

#endif  // VSTOR_HPP
```

I'd value any concrete feedback.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Specialization of VisitableListVariant that unfolds any list-like template
```

You don't want this. Imagine what happens when someone inherits from `VisitableListVariant<std::string, int>` versus when they inherit from `VisitableListVariant<std::string>` alone. (Recall that `std::string` is of the form `TT<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`; so it will match this specialization.)

You don't need this specialization — parameter packs can be passed around without wrapping, just fine. And it's harmful. So eliminate it.

Your test code is *crazy* convoluted. With all the comments removed, it's like this:

```
struct VisitablesVariant;
struct Base : VisitableFor<VisitablesVariant> {};
template <typename...> struct AnyList;
struct D1;
struct D2;
using ListOfVisitables = AnyList<D1, D2>;

struct VisitablesVariant : VisitableListVariant<ListOfVisitables> {
    using VisitableListVariant<ListOfVisitables>::VisitableListVariant;
};

template <typename Impl> struct BaseImpl : VisitableImpl<Impl, Base> {};
struct D1 : BaseImpl<D1> {};
struct D2 : BaseImpl<D2> {};
```

Disentangled, IIUC, it'd be like this:

```
struct D1;
struct D2;
struct Base : VisitableFor<VisitableListVariant<D1, D2>> {};
struct D1 : VisitableImpl<D1, Base> {};
struct D2 : VisitableImpl<D2, Base> {};
```

And I would rather see something like this:

```
struct D1;
struct D2;
struct Base : Visitable<D1, D2> {};
struct D1 : Base {};
struct D2 : Base {};
```

Implementation of this "cleaner" design is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

If you're using this *only* for visiting polymorphic hierarchies, you might be interested in this alternative design: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/09/29/oop-visit/

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
struct D1 : Base {};
struct D2 : Base {};

const Base& b = d2;
std::string_view sv = my::visit<D1, D2>(b, Overloaded{
    [](const D1& d1) { return "d1"; },
    [](const D2& d2) { return "d2"; },
});
assert(sv == "d2");
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
That's a valid point about list-like specializations being harmful.

Comment: > Disentangled, IIUC, it'd be like this:
> ```
> ...
> struct Base : VisitableFor<VisitableListVariant<D1, D2>> {};
> ...
> ```
I'm afraid you've not understood that correctly. Such a design would require the base declaration to know the full declaration of the list of all its visitables, which is not intended. That's why `VisitablesVariant` is forward-declared for the `Base` declaration. The test comments are clunky, but try to state that requirement. It's hard to express the requirements of physical design in unit tests, but I might improve it, so thanks for showing it's not obvious.

Comment: Thanks for linking the blog post. Great stuff. I'll compare to your approach. From the first look, from the physical design perspective your solution looks as decoupled as I wanted it to be in the call site. However, you allow for cast errors in runtime, which I wanted disallowed by compilation.

Comment: I'm also interested how the performance would compare between your and mine approach. I'll add some tests when I find a minute.

Comment: Okay, I've played with it in Godbolt a bit. https://godbolt.org/z/ofq986 Take a look at my rearranging of the test's pieces (I still think your way is "tangled" and I'm "disentangling" it), and also IMO I've improved the indentation on the `Overloaded` stuff. (I also had to `#include <functional>`, and declare the deduction guide unconditionally for GCC's benefit.)

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'll apply your suggestions on github. Regards!